# % based height, turned dynamicly into pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, percentage

**I am looking for an easy way to do the following:**

I am building a website, and i have a .content class and its height is = height:auto; and its width = width:80%;
but i do not want the div to become "TOO" bit vertically, when i am scaling it.

**Question:**

Is there a javascript 'if' statement that checks for the height of a div, and then is able to put overflow-y:scroll; on the element if it gets too big, say 400px vertically?

Note that, the div has no height in the css. It is set to auto.
thx

Comment: .. just set a minimum height `min-height: 400px;` ?

Comment: You could also set `min-height` in css, and `overflow-y`.

Comment: point is that a scroll bar is ugly for my design, so i want the scrollbar to only appear if the div gets too big.

And i assume you mean max-height, right?

Comment: Sorry - yes.  `max-height:400px` and `overflow-y:auto`

Comment: of course, Auto. sorry i didn't see this earlier, This is the perfect answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do it via CSS, then the jQuery functions you're looking for are:

```
$("#element").outerHeight() and $("#element").outerWidth()
```

They return the computed height and width of elements, rather than the height and width that was explicitly set.
So,

```
if ($("#element").outerWidth() > 400) {
    $("#element").width(400);
    $("#element").css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}
```

Comment: it looks right. But practically it doesn't work in my code, do i have to determine when it checks for the current height?

Comment: Try console.log ($('#element').outerWidth()) and see whats the output

Comment: And remember to replace #element with the actual name of your element

Comment: I just replaced .css('width', 400) with .width(400). Try it now and let me know

Comment: wish i could, but i have no experience in debugging using firebug

Comment: To make it simple, i am making responsive design, but i do not want a sertain div to get too high, but there is text inside the div, so a max-height, doesn't fix it, so i want the scroll bar to appear when the max-height, is reached. but i cannot find any code for this.

Comment: But part is not working with the solution I gave you? Here is the jsfiddle with two alerts, one before adjusting and one after adjusting: http://jsfiddle.net/MTFDf/

Comment: But it didn't work Dynamicly when i scaled down my window, to check for people with a lower resolution than mine

Answer (score 0):

If you are going the jQuery way, adding to @ieeehh, first include jQuery. Then assuming the element has the id of `#element`

```
$(function(){
      if ($("#element").outerHeight() > 400) {
           $("#element").width(400).css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
      }
});
```

Comment: i am aware of how to use jquery to some extend :)
But this unfortunately does not do the job.
And is it on purpose that you keep saying outerWidth, when it has nothing to do with the width?